# What are Key Event for BRACKETS in Java?

Tags: java, swing, key, awt

Hi how can I detect **{** and **}**. I found no code for them in [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Comment: These are called (curly) braces. Brackets are `[` and `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `VK_BRACELEFT` and `VK_BRACERIGHT`.